# After filtering the list, if want to check original list returns wrong list size

Tags: java, android, arraylist, filter

I have a list of merchants, I am applying filter to it to search by address or a name, filter works fine. it gives proper list of filtered results. But if I again empty the  edit text I should see the original list, but I see different count than the original.

Example, in list I have 7 merchants, I do filter it and it shows two filtered merchants in the list, and now if I empty the edit text I see only 5 merchants , unable to see the original list of 7 merchants.

Adapter:

```
 public class SearchedMerchantsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{
    static final int LOAD_MERCHANTS = 0;
    private Context context;
    public ArrayList<Merchants> list;
    public ArrayList<Merchants> baselist = new ArrayList<>();


    public SearchedMerchantsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Merchants> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
        this.baselist = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        Object obj = list.get(position);

        if (obj instanceof Merchants) return LOAD_MERCHANTS;

        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        int viewType = holder.getItemViewType();
        switch (viewType) {

            case LOAD_MERCHANTS:
                LoadSearchedMerchants loadSearchedMerchants = (LoadSearchedMerchants) holder;
                retriveAllMerchants(loadSearchedMerchants, position);
                break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        switch (viewType) {
            case LOAD_MERCHANTS:
                View v_image_msg = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_merchant_layout, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new LoadSearchedMerchants(v_image_msg);
                break;
        }

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public void retriveAllMerchants(final LoadSearchedMerchants holder, int position) {

        final Merchants data = (Merchants) list.get(position);

        holder.tv_kiarana_name.setText(data.getKirana_name());
        holder.tv_address.setText(data.getMerchant_address());



        holder.lay_row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent i = new Intent(context, MerchantProfileActivity.class);

                i.putExtra("cont_name",data.getMerchant_name());
                i.putExtra("kirana_name",data.getKirana_name());
                i.putExtra("email_id",data.getEmail_id());
                i.putExtra("phone_no",data.getPhone());
                i.putExtra("address",data.getMerchant_address());

                context.startActivity(i);

            }
        });

        holder.btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final SessionData sessionData;
                final String sessionUserId,access_token;

                sessionData=new SessionData(context);
                sessionUserId = sessionData.getString("user_id","-1");
                access_token = sessionData.getString("api_key", "-1");

                new SendRequestAsyncTask(context).execute(sessionUserId,access_token,data.getMerchant_id().toString());

            }
        });

    }

    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                final FilterResults oReturn = new FilterResults();
                final ArrayList<Merchants> results = new ArrayList<>();

                if (constraint != null) {
                    if (baselist != null && baselist.size() > 0) {
                        for (final Merchants g : baselist) {
                            if (g.getKirana_name()
                                    .contains(constraint.toString()) || g.getMerchant_address().contains(constraint.toString()))
                                results.add(g);
                        }
                    }
                    oReturn.values = results;
                }
                return oReturn;
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                          FilterResults results) {
                list = (ArrayList<Merchants>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

What can be the reason for this? Thank you..

Comment: use holder.getAdapterPosition instead of position

Comment: when I load the list, list contains 7 merchants but after filtering the list contains 5 merchants. @MayurRaval

Comment: where should I use holder.getAdapterPosition? @Divyesh

Comment: final Merchants data = (Merchants) list.get(position);

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ?

```
@Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                final FilterResults oReturn = new FilterResults();
                final ArrayList<Merchants> results = new ArrayList<>();


                if (charSequence != null && charSequence.length() > 0) {
                    if (baselist != null && baselist.size() > 0) {
                        for (final Merchants g : baselist) {
                            if (g.getKirana_name()
                                    .contains(constraint.toString()) || g.getMerchant_address().contains(constraint.toString()))
                                results.add(g);
                        }
                    }
                    oReturn.values = results;
                    oReturn.count = results.size();
                }
                else
                 {
                   oReturn.values = baselist;
                   oReturn.count = baselist.size();
                 }
                return oReturn;
            }
```

**Update**

Create one Method in Adapter.. Comment out `getFilter()` and interface `Filterable`

```
public void filterData(String compareString)
{
list.clear();
if (baselist != null && baselist.size() > 0) {
                        for (final Merchants g : baselist) {
                            if (g.getKirana_name()
                                    .contains(compareString) || g.getMerchant_address().contains(compareString))
                                list.add(g);
                        }
                    }
notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And Last call this Method From your `edittext` change listener

like `adapter.filterData("StringwhichisChangedFromEdittext")`

Hope this help.

Comment: Still I can see only 5 merchants. :-(

Comment: what is fResults?

Comment: now i see only 4 merchants.. :-( whats wrong with this.

Comment: I want to compare each character if present in the string. I tried to change string with charsequence but dose not give filtered result, filtered list is blank

Comment: @Sid , did you try with Updated code? please see edited some Code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131711/discussion-between-sid-and-mayur-raval).

Answer (score 0):

Create this method in adapter:

```
public Item getItemAtPosition(int position)
    {
        return list.get(position);
    }
```

Now, when click action occurs just call this method:

```
adapter.getItemAtPosition(position).getMerchant_name()
```

Comment: I dont want item position, i just want to filter the list.

Comment: you can use addTextChangedListener to filter list

Comment: I am using it, list filters well but after filtering if I empty the edit text I get wrong size of list than original list.

Answer (score 0):

Return the entire list if user enters nothing

```
 public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            final FilterResults oReturn = new FilterResults();
            final ArrayList<Merchants> results = new ArrayList<>();

             if(TextUtils.isEmpty(constraint)){
              oReturn.values = baselist==null?new ArrayList() : baselist ;
              return oReturn.values ;
              }

            if (constraint != null) {
                if (baselist != null && baselist.size() > 0) {
                    for (final Merchants g : baselist) {
                        if (g.getKirana_name()
                                .contains(constraint.toString()) || g.getMerchant_address().contains(constraint.toString()))
                            results.add(g);
                    }
                }
                oReturn.values = results;
            }
            return oReturn;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                      FilterResults results) {
            list = (ArrayList<Merchants>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}
```